# Вшить dll библиотеку в проект

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

У меня проект на выходе состоит из одного файла. Решил я в проекте использовать стороннюю dll библиотеку. Как сделать так чтобы моя программа всё так же состояла из одного файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сторонняя DLL - тоже .NET-сборка, то попробуйте [`ILMerge`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge):

> ILMerge is a utility that can be used to merge multiple .NET assemblies into a single assembly. ILMerge takes a set of input assemblies and merges them into one target assembly.